# Running all tests but stop and debug one of them

Tags: .net, unit-testing, debugging, nunit, testcase

I am testing a `.NET` dll and i have written 5 `NUnit` tests against it.All tests share a common object that gets initialized in the `OneTimeSetUp`.When i press `RunAll` `4/5` tests return correct.The fifth one works fine when running alone.

Is there any way to put the breakpoint in your target `testcase`,select `Run-all` and stop where you need? I need to inspect the state of the shared object in the test that fails.

Is it possible?

**Example**

```
public class State
{
  public int Value;
}

public class Tests{
   public State state=new State();
   [Testcase]
    public void Test1()
    {
      state.Value=1;
     }

   [Testcase]
   public void Test2()
   {
      state.Value=2;
   }
   ......
   [Testcase]
   public void TestN()
   {
     -----breakpoint
   }
}
```

Comment: please not that you are not in control over the order your test methods are executed in. Shared state is not a good thing in unit testing, the test should be self contained and able to run in any order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try to use "debug" instead of "run all". Your run should stop on your breakpoint.